How to disable string processing in wikipedia-1.4.0 API?
When using the https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/ API, wikipedia==1.4.0, it seems that when accessing the page, the library would first do some string processing to alter the inputs, e.g.
import wikipedia
wikipedia.page('Backstreet Boys')

[out]:
PageError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 wikipedia.page('Backstreet Boys')

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py:276, in page(title, pageid, auto_suggest, redirect, preload)
    273     except IndexError:
    274       # if there is no suggestion or search results, the page doesn't exist
    275       raise PageError(title)
--> 276   return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
    277 elif pageid is not None:
    278   return WikipediaPage(pageid=pageid, preload=preload)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py:299, in WikipediaPage.__init__(self, title, pageid, redirect, preload, original_title)
    296 else:
    297   raise ValueError("Either a title or a pageid must be specified")
--> 299 self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)
    301 if preload:
    302   for prop in ('content', 'summary', 'images', 'references', 'links', 'sections'):

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py:345, in WikipediaPage.__load(self, redirect, preload)
    343 if 'missing' in page:
    344   if hasattr(self, 'title'):
--> 345     raise PageError(self.title)
    346   else:
    347     raise PageError(pageid=self.pageid)

PageError: Page id "back street boys" does not match any pages. Try another id!

How to disable string processing in wikipedia-1.4.0 API?

Try adding auto_suggest=False

@ThomasWeller If you are referring to me, why does it matter to you that I edit whatever question that comes across my feed?

@InSync: it doesn't matter, I just think that it's a nice coincidence. Backstreet Boys vs. NSync was one of the most discussed topics in 1990s or so. Long time ago. (I liked neither of them, so it wasn't particularly of interest to me at the time)

Use the auto_suggest option:

auto_suggest - let Wikipedia find a valid page title for the query

wikipedia.page('Backstreet Boys', auto_suggest=False)

